# SQL left outer join but detect what row were "filled" with nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN with a one to many relationship. Here is an example

Table A

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| a1   | a2   | a3   |
| b1   | b2   | b3   |
| c1   | c2   | c3   |
+------+------+------+
```

Table B

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| x1   | a2   | NULL |
| y1   | b2   | y3   |
+------+------+------+
```

I am joining tables on Col2 so:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.col2 = tableB.col2
WHERE tableB.col3 IS NOT NULL
```

This query returns the second row of tableA as expected. My problem is that I also need row 3 of tableA because it does not have a related record on tableB. As the JOIN clause is "filling" with nulls when the association is not found, then the query is not returning that row. So to summarize, I need all records from table A that have an associated record from table B AND tableB.col3 IS NOT NULL, AND all records from table B that do not have an associated record on table B.

Expected output (what I need):

```
+------+------+------+
| b1   | b2   | b3   |
| c1   | c2   | c3   |
+------+------+------+
```

Any ideas on how can I retrieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean "AND all records from table A that [do] not have an associated record on table B" at the end of the longer paragraph?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting the question as:

> I need all records from table A that have an associated record from
>   table B AND tableB.col3 IS NULL AND all records from table A that have
>   no associated record on table B.

This is a bit more challenging.  I think the following query implements the logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN
     tableB b
     ON a.col2 = b.col2
WHERE (a.col2 = b.col2 and b.col3 is null) or
      (b.col2 is null)
```

EDIT:

Based on your edit, you seem to want:

> I need all records from table A that have an associated record from
>   table B AND tableB.col3 IS NOT NULL AND all records from table A that have
>   no associated record on table B.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN
     tableB b
     ON a.col2 = b.col2
WHERE (a.col2 = b.col2 and b.col3 is not null) or
      (b.col2 is null)
```

Comment: Ahh, so when the join happens b.col2 will be null because it does not matched any record on table b?

Comment: @Ziggurat . . . Yes.  When checking to see if a `join` matches rows, it is a good idea to use the key for the `join` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3
  from tablea a
  left join tableb b
    on a.col2 = b.col2
 where b.col3 is not null
    or b.col2 is null
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e98a5/12/0

Comment: Sorry, will edit the question, I am actually using left outer join. And the suggested ON is already on the sentence. Problem is when there is no record associated with the table A record. I need that too, but the join is filtering it due to the not null condition.

Comment: @Ziggurat your question contradicts itself elsewhere as well. Please provide expected output as that is the clearest way to understand what you want.